# Error: the type or namespace UI doesnt exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, namespaces, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I need to use System.Web.UI in a class library project.

```
using System.Web.UI;

namespace OnlinePdViewer
{
    public class DisplayPd
    {
    }
}
```

I get compile error when using System.Web.UI statement:

"The type or namespace name 'UI' does not exist in the namespace in the 'System.Web' are you missing an assembly reference?"

I tried to add the reference System.Web, but COM does not include System.Web dll.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Select the 'Project' menu option
2. Select 'Add Reference'
3. Select 'Framework'
4. Find and check the checkbox next to the 'System.Web' DLL and select <kbd>OK</kbd>.

The error will be removed.